# Creating a pandas dataframe column based on classifier equivalence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Background:  I have used two different ML classifiers on data to arrive at three different classifications (2, 1 and 0). The nature of the classes themselves are not relevant here.  I want to compare the results of each classifier and segregate data in further dataframes based on matches.  Below is where I am creating a dataframe from another dataframe to analyze based on the classifier results:

Step 1:

```
analyze['noclean_match'] = analyze['vader_class_form']==analyze['roberta_class_formatted']

analyze['clean_match'] = analyze['vader_class_no_SW'] == analyze['roberta_class_nosw']
```

As you can see, I am attempting to create new dataframe columns based on equivalency of the integer value (2, 1, or 0) on each row of the dataframe under the existing columns.

Step 2:  Now I create a dataframe for visual inspection of the resulting classes and reset the index:

```
manual_exam = analyze[analyze['clean_match'] == True].sample(n=50)
manual_exam.reset_index(drop=True, inplace = True)
```

What I would expect is that in all cases of the 50 samples, that each of my rows should have the same result (2, 1 or 0) for each model.  However, when inspecting the data, this is not the case.  As an example:

```
print(manual_exam['vader_class_form'].iloc[1])
print(manual_exam['roberta_class_formatted'].iloc[1])
```

Yields this:

```
2
1
```

Instead of

```
2
2
```

So I know I am doing something incorrectly, but I'm not sure if it is the conditional logic in step 1 to create a column based on equivalency in rows, or if it is step 2, where I am creating a new dataframe based on the boolean logic after selecting the column to base the dataframe from.

Any thoughts on how I can remedy this?  Here is my dataframe information:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1405 entries, 0 to 33
Data columns (total 8 columns):
 #   Column                   Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------                   --------------  ----- 
 0   job_id                   1405 non-null   object
 1   formatted                1405 non-null   object
 2   vader_class_form         1405 non-null   int64 
 3   roberta_class_formatted  1405 non-null   int64 
 4   vader_class_no_SW        1405 non-null   int64 
 5   roberta_class_nosw       1405 non-null   int64 
 6   noclean_match            1405 non-null   bool  
 7   clean_match              1405 non-null   bool
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, e.g. pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3]}) for the input and the expected output

Comment: I updated my dataframe comments in the original question for better readability

Comment: I was able to solve my problem using a different approach, but I'm not sure this is the most efficient/elegant way:

` manual_exam = analyze[analyze['vader_class_form']== analyze['roberta_class_formatted']].sample(n=50)`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem using a different approach, but I'm not sure this is the most efficient/elegant way:

`manual_exam = analyze[analyze['vader_class_form']== analyze['roberta_class_formatted']].sample(n=50)`